# Ubuntu won't let me log in

Tags: ubuntu, boot, login

I have a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. Each on a different drive.
I had been using both without a problem. Yesterday during the day, I switched to Windows, then at night I tried to switch to Ubuntu but although it would seem to load everything as usual, when trying to enter into an account (any of the 3), it would return me back to the same page where you choose your account and enter your credentials.

Then I rebooted and tried the next choice in line, but that's when I got this error:

```
"Failed to enable subscription: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1. Failed to fully start up daemon: Input/output error"
```

Then I rebooted in Safemode, and tried "dpkg" (repair broken packages). And rebooted to normal. But the problem persisted.

I rebooted in Safemode again, and tried "fsck" (check all file systems). And rebooted to normal. But the problem persisted.

I didn't see a choice to boot from previous versions:
[image: Safemode choices]

Today I ran Boot Repair Disk.
It said it successfully repaired the booting files.
However, the problem still persists (...when trying to enter into an account, it would return me back to the same page where you choose your account and enter your credentials.).

I had this problem before (different installation though), I seem to recall it was advised to change the permissions, but I can't find that information.

I thought of restoring previous backups with Backups, but I don't know how to target the location where Ubuntu is, as opposed to the USB drive (assuming this is a viable idea).

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Did you set up a root password? If not, I think you can do so from safe-mode command line. Then use `Alt-Fn` (`n` = 1..6) from a normal boot, log in as root, and use the command-line user maintenance functions: `Alt-F7` will bring back the GUI. If this doesn't work, try something like `apt-get -f upgrade` and reboot.

Comment: Thanks AFH. Just to be sure that we are on the same page on this: I do have a GUI when Ubuntu loads, so bringing it back is not the issue. Maybe the image I posted to show my Safemode choices is misleading you (?). It shows that way only while in Safemode. Unless there's something I ignore? (which is always possible).

Comment: No, I wasn't misled. I referred to command-line utilities because the two environments (safe-mode root shell and `Alt-Fn` root log-in) both give shell prompts. On an earlier Ubuntu, I was able to start a new, root X-session from `Alt-Fn` and this appeared on `Alt-F8`, but this didn't work the last time I tried it, and I wasn't curious enough to trace why. If this works for you, then the GUI tools, such as `synaptic`, will be available.

Comment: Good, I am glad I was wrong about that then.
But you lost me about using Synaptic, how would it help me now?

Comment: You can use it to find and reinstall packages, such as `login`, though it's only a GUI front-end to `apt-get` and some of the other `apt*` utilities. I find it a lot easier than Software Boutique.

Comment: I booted up, this time I chose the 2nd option: Ubuntu Advanced Options. Then I saw the list of the previous versions, I chose the previous one (1 back), and it logged in just fine!!! 
Now, should I expect it to do it again on its own? Or should I be taking  additional steps to ensure it'll login fine next time?

Comment: It never occurred to me that you wouldn't have tried that, but I should have mentioned it. Since we don't know what went wrong, it's impossible to say what steps to take, apart from taking frequent back-ups, obviously. It's possible that now you've logged in under the previous kernel, you might in passing have corrected whatever was wrong from the current one, so it's worth checking it again. If not, it may well be fixed in the next software update. It is possible to exclude a specific kernel when you run `update-grub`, so that your previous version appears as the default.

Comment: Assuming I am able to open an X session, what command line will I need to reinstall the "login" package? And any other package?

Comment: If you can open an X-session, then you are best to use something like `synaptic`, which has a context menu `Mark for reinstall` for installed packages. You don't need an X-session to use the command line `apt-get remove login; apt-get install login`. Make absolutely sure you are on-line before you use `apt-get remove` or you may get into a hopeless muddle. You can use `purge` instead of `remove` if you want to start with a clean configuration. When working with elements as fundamental as this you _must_ make a full partition back-up first.

Comment: Finally tried it, but none of the Alt-Fn keys opened an X session, or similar. Maybe there's more to this than I had thought. I guess I should just reinstall Ubuntu, do a good clone of it once installed and setup the way I need it, that way I won't have to go through this again.

Comment: If you log in with `Alt-Fn` command-line shell you should be able to start an X-session from there: see `man X`.